# Java Superclass Methods: keyword "this" vs "super"

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

Say I have:

```
public class A<T>{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

and I create

```
public class B extends A<Integer>{

}
```

What is the difference between accessing the print() function in A via super.print() versus this.print()? Both seem to access the method.

Comment: No difference unless you have overridden it.

Answer (score 2):

`super.print()` is intended to call the superclass method from the child method. If you wanted to, for example, override `print` in `A` to say something else *and* print `"Hi"`, you could write

```
public void print() {
  super.print();
  System.out.println("I'm a B, by the way :)");
}
```

Calling `this.print()` here would infinitely call the same function which would hang your program.

Now, you *can* use `super` in other contexts, but you really shouldn't. What it says is "ignore the current class and make a static call to my parent's implementation". That makes sense (and is useful) in an overridden method. It's just confusing in other contexts.

So, if `this.print()` makes sense (which it does *unless* you're overriding `print`), you should use that, as it's what everyone will expect. `super.print()` should *only* be used in an override of the `print` method, since you have no other option.